# SSH - How can I use a forwarded port (via multiple hops) to open a remote shell terminal?

Tags: shell, ssh, portforwarding

To simply explain my problem:

I'm at A with access to B (which has access to C) but what I really need is to have access to C at A via a shell terminal.

Now if I have port 1234 at A forwarded to port 9999 at B which is forwarded to some port X at C, can I accomplish my goal?

Note that I do not know the host name of C.

Comment: but you know at least the IP address of C, right ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

on machine A:

```
ssh user@machineB -L 2222:machineC_hostname_orIP:22
```

Then connect on localport 2222 on machine A and the SSH magic will forward that connection to machineC:22 via machineB